# How can I create a new dropdown list only when a certain element is selected in an MVC3 app?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, client-side

I have a DropDownFor on my View and I'm looking to create another DropDownFor **only if** a particular SelectList item from the first DropDownFor is selected.

To clarify, if my DropDownFor has two possible choices, "A" and "B", and if "B" is selected, I want another DropDownFor to display on the page. If "A" is selected, I want nothing more to happen to the page.

How can I implement this?

Comment: jQuery! (same thing almost) What have you tried first?

Comment: I haven't really tried anything. I thought I would ask before jumping into the fire. Also, I'm a complete noob at jQuery and JavaScript, so any code to help me get started would be VERY appreciated!

Comment: @Nate Wait one minute, I thought I was Nate... ;)

Comment: @Nate No, their is only one Nate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

## script (using jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#optionOne').change(function (){
        if($(this).val() === 'b') {
            $('#options').append("<select><option>newset</option></select>");
        }            
    });
});​
```

## markup

```
<div id="options">
    <select id="optionOne">
        <option>a</option>
        <option>b</option>
    </select>
​</div>​
```

JSFiddle Example of the above code -- http://jsfiddle.net/NpSPj/1/

Comment: I might go with an initially hidden select element that gets shown, or creating it dynamically based on JSON data returned from AJAX, but there are several ways it could be accomplished.

Comment: @Nate Thanks! This should get me rolling.

Comment: @MrOBrian I agree. This is a baseline proof of concept. Building the second one based on Ajax request, and/or hiding it initially and showing it on select would both be good options. This solution could be adapted to both options with a bit more effort and specific info based on requirements.